# MySQL config recommendation script

Tags: mysql, configuration

I want to be able to get an recommendation of what values I should set my my.cnf to. Especially the query_cache_size and join_buffer_size. Is there a script out there that can monitor my server and give me a recommendation? Or any other solution?

I found a few scripts, but their recommendations did not give any specific numbers...

Answer (score 2):

Written by RackerHacker, MySQL Tuner should help: http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl - you'll be lucky to find one that suggests the actual values though as these are heavily dependant on the code you're running.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer well known tuning-primer.sh

http://www.day32.com/MySQL/